# Determining the kernel of a function and finding the direct image of a set

Tags: functions

Suppose we have a function $f:Z\setminus\{0\} → Z\setminus\{0\}$ such that :

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
3x+1 & \text{when x is odd} \\ 
x/2 & \text{when x is even} 
\end{cases}
$$

How would we determine the kernel of this function and how would we find the direct image of the set $Z\setminus\{0\}$ ?

Comment: Is it have the kernel? The function looks like not algebraic so we can not talk about the kernel of the function.

Comment: What do you mean by _direct image_? I also agree with @HanulJeon that it makes no sense to talk about a _kernel_ if we don’t have a morphism of (algebraic) structures, as we need a concept of _zero_.

Comment: @Jendrik: If $f$ is a function and $A$ is a [sub]set [of the domain], the direct image of $A$ is $\{f(a)\mid a\in A\}$. Often written as $f(A)$ or $f[A]$ (and sometimes in set theory as $f''A$ also).

Comment: Why call it direct as opposed to just image? Perhaps a subtlety that I missed.

Comment: By kernel I mean a binary relation ρ such that x1 ρ x2 iff f(x1) = f(x2) (where x1 and x2 belong to the domain of the function).
So for example x1=1 and x2=8 have the same image.
By direct image I mean what Asaf Karagila said.

Answer (score 0):

To find the kernel, you need to find some way to neatly specify which elements get sent to the same place. Obviously if $x=y$, $f(x)=f(y)$, so that's not interesting. So we look for cases where $x\neq y$ and yet $f(x)=f(y)$. Here's a proof by cases.

Suppose two elements $x, y$ are distinct and share the same $f$-image. Then suppose they're both odd, so $$f(x)=3x+1=3y+1=f(y)$$
Clearly this implies $x=y$, so this isn't the interesting case we're looking for.

Now suppose both are even, so $$f(x)=\frac{x}{2}=\frac{y}{2}=f(y)$$ Oh dear, $x=y$ again. Not interesting. So whenever $x, y$ have the same *parity*, they could only have the same $f$-image if they were equal in the first place.

So the interesting case for your relation must occur when $x$ is even and $y$ is odd (or vice versa). Then $$f(x)=\frac{x}{2}=3y+1=f(y)$$
Now we can solve for $x$ in terms of $y$ i.e. $x=6y+2$. So your relation can be defined by this equation; $$x\rho y \quad\text{iff}\quad x=6y+2 \quad\text{(or}\quad y=6x+2)$$

Now if you think about that, you'll realise that means every odd number gets paired with exactly even number, and they both get mapped to an even number. So to the image of $f$ can only contain even numbers. Now can you find a way to prove that every even number is reached by the function $f$? If you manage that, then you have shown $f(\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\})=2\mathbb{Z}$. Et voila.